# Do we have possible solutions for bulk approval of page in workflow

Tags: workflow, workbox

Do we have any possible solution in Sitecore to able to track and approve a page and all associated components in same workflow all at once rather than one item at a time, and keep track of it without use of creating spreadsheets to keep track of it.

Have explored the workflow solution. There is too much content and no way to search for items or determine easily to which project or release they belong to.
We are using sitecore 8.2 version.

Comment: @Vlad lobagiu unfortunately no.

Comment: It's the same question, will close this one.